# Set a UIView in a fixed proportional position from the Right Edge of screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Say, I have a `UIImageView` or any object and I set it in a `UIView` as subView with `CGRectMake` like this:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(266, 0, 30, 30)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageDicKey objectAtIndex:section]]];
    [headerView addSubview:imgView];
```

Here I set the position of my `imgView` like `CGRectMake(266, 0, 30, 30)];` and it counts it's position form the left `x position` (which is 266). What If I want to set my `imgView`'s position from right side of the screen? So that,in different width of iPhone screen it shows in a same ratio position. But which will be counted it's position from right edge.
Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not hard coding the exact positions and instead calculating the x and y. That way it will help for different sized screens so it's not an exact position and rather it's based upon the views' size.

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];

CGFloat padding = 20;   // amount for padding
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);   // size of imageView
CGPoint startPos = CGPointMake(headerView.frame.size.width - padding - size.width, 0);  // starting position for imageView

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startPos.x, startPos.y, size.width, size.height)]; [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageDicKey objectAtIndex:section]]]; [headerView addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is what I was asking. :D
Perfectly working (y)....Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the ImageView's width is 30 and the x coordinate is 266 from the left side, it makes the x coordinate from the right side 296.